# Can I test an npm optimized build using `npm test` or some other technique?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, npm, production-environment

I'm working on a React.js project using `node`. I usually run the unit tests with `npm test` to make sure all of them pass, then I create an optimized build using `npm run build`. The optimized build is minimized and bundled.

Because it's a React.js project, the `package.json` uses the `react-scripts` under the hood:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "lint": "standard"
  },
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to run the tests on the optimized build, so when I give this build to a user, the user can also run the tests to make sure everything works on his/her environment.

I'm using an earlier version of node (v8.11.4) and npm (5.6.0).

Comment: why don;t you run command sequentially, first run test then make a build. Unit testing is for development purposes. And fix those bugs in the meantime to make app functional